# SDL2, Mac OS X, and OpenGL: How to avoid including both gl.h and gl3.h?

Tags: macos, opengl, sdl, sdl-2

I'm working on an SDL2 application using the OpenGL 3.2 core profile.  When I compile, I get the following warning:

> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/gl.h:5:2: warning:
>   #warning gl.h and gl3.h are both included. Compiler will not invoke errors if using removed OpenGL functionality. [-Wcpp]

I have to assume that SDL is including gl.h somewhere, because my only includes are as follows:

```
#define GL3_PROTOTYPES

#include <OpenGL/gl3.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
```

While I can simply ignore this, it has already led to one hard-to-find bug when I accidentally used an enum value not available in the core profile.  Is there some way to prevent gl.h from being included?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Take a look at `/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/gl.h`, you should see a pretty standard include guard on the first line: `#ifndef __gl_h_`. If you look at `gl3.h` you will notice an equally standard include guard for `__gl3_h_`. This warning is only triggered when both are defined and `GL_DO_NOT_WARN_IF_MULTI_GL_VERSION_HEADERS_INCLUDED` is undefined.

The easiest way to prevent including anything from within `gl.h` would be to `#define __gl_h_` before it is ever included. To avoid messing up your actual code with something nasty like:

```c
#ifdef __APPLE__
# define __gl_h_
# define GL_DO_NOT_WARN_IF_MULTI_GL_VERSION_HEADERS_INCLUDED
#endif
```

I would suggest adding `-D__gl_h_ -DGL_DO_NOT_WARN_IF_MULTI_GL_VERSION_HEADERS_INCLUDED` as a compiler switch to your Makefile when you target OS X (so that no matter where `gl.h` is indirectly included from, it never does anything). This really is not the right way to go about tackling this, and that warning was generated for a reason (which you pointed out in your question -- deprecated OpenGL tokens will not generate compiler warnings / errors when both headers are included).

I think SDL2 itself ought to have some pre-processor mechanism to do what I did above with `#ifdef __APPLE__` but in lieu of that, this will get the job done. It is not an error by any means to include both, OS X just provides a handy mechanism to generate compiler errors when deprecated tokens (e.g. `GL_MODELVIEW`) are used in a project that is supposed to be core 3+.

On other platforms whether you are using core OpenGL 3+ is not so black and white at compile-time, so the compiler cannot be used for this purpose. It is one of those things that Apple does just because they can; "think different."

Comment: Great answer.  It looks like defining `__gl_h_` causes some problems internally in SDL, but that's a separate issue.  I'll see what I can find directly from their community.

Answer (score 1):

This warning goes away in the 2.0.4 release candidate of SDL2.
Temp link to release candidate was shared on SDL mailing list.
http://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=11305